# How to fix the error DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER?

Tags: sql-server-2005, dts, ssis

I am getting the following error when my DTS package is scheduled:

`Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER`

I am not sure how to get my DTS packages to execute. They run fine when I manually execute them

I am running SQL Server 2005. DTS Packages were created using the Import/Export Wizard.

Comment: Most likely a permission issue, what user does the job run under and does that user have all the needed permissions?

Comment: runs under sqlserveragent which has full permissions

Comment: For me, this was because I'd renamed my project and it had defaulted back to running debug in 64-bit mode, which made my 32-bit Oracle connection quite unhappy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed authentication from SQL Server to Windows Auth and it did the trick. Not sure the technical reason why.

Answer (score 1):

https://imgalib.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/how-to-solve-ssis-error-code-0xc020801c0xc004700c0xc0047017/

Its the issue with excel processing. Required to change default Runtime. 
Navigate to “Debugging” option from left panel and from Right panel change Run64BitRuntime value to false. in project properties.

Check the link above for detailed steps.

Comment: In Vs 2017 go to your project setting and from there expand configuration properties -> debugging -> Run64BitRuntime

Answer (score 0):

When a package is scheduled, it normally runs under the context and persmissions of the SQL Server Agent.

Does the package make a connection to a drive letter or other mechanism which is not available to the unattended sqlserver agent account?

Comment: sqlserveragent was granted full permissions, but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the login/password combination in any of the connections in the connection manager of the DTS, or some problem with the access to the server where the db is located.

Comment: if it works manually, i would assume the login/password is correct. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If your server name is over 31 characters long (including hostname), then it will not fire.

Comment: servername is less than 31 chars